# Plot multiple days data of multiple homes in Facet form of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I have hourly timeseries data of three homes(`H1, H2, H3`) for continuous five days created as

```
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.frame(H1 = rnorm(24*5,200,2),H2 = rnorm(24*5,150,2),H3 = rnorm(24*5,50,2)) # hourly data of three homes for 5 days
timestamp <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01"),as.POSIXct("2016-01-05 23:59:59"), by = "hour") # create timestamp
dt$timestamp <- timestamp
```

Now I want to plot data homewise in facet form; accordingly I melt dataframe as

```
tempdf <- reshape2::melt(dt,id.vars="timestamp") # melt data for faceting
colnames(tempdf) <- c("time","var","val") # rename so as not to result in conflict with another melt inside geom_line
```

Within each facet (for each home), I want to see the values of all the five days in line plot form (each facet should contain 5 lines corresponding to different days). Accordingly,

```
ggplot(tempdf) + facet_wrap(~var) + 
  geom_line(data = function(x) {
    locdat <- xts(x$val,x$time)# create timeseries object for easy splitting
    sub <- split.xts(locdat,f="days") # split data daywise of considered home
    sub2 <- sapply(sub, function(y) return(coredata(y))) # arrange data in matrix form
    df_sub2 <- as.data.frame(sub2)
    df_sub2$timestamp <- index(sub[[1]]) # forcing same timestamp for all days [okay with me]
    df_melt <- reshape2::melt(df_sub2,id.vars="timestamp") # melt to plot inside each facet
    #return(df_melt)
    df_melt
  }, aes(x=timestamp, y=value,group=variable,color=variable),inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

I have forced the same timestamp for all the days of a home to make plotting simple. With above code, I get plot as
[image]

Only problem with above plot is that, It is plotting same data in all the facets. Ideally, `H1` facet should contain data of home 1 only and `H2` facet should contain data of home 2. I know that I am not able to pass homewise data in `geom_line()`, can anyone help to do in correct manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you may find it more efficient to modify the data *outside* the call to `ggplot` rather than inside it (allows closer inspection of what is happening at each step, at least in my opinion).

Here, I am using `lubridate` to generate two new columns. The first holds only the date (and not the time) to allow faceting on that. The second holds the full datetime, but I then modify the date so that they are all the same. This leaves only the times as mattering (and we can suppress the chosen date in the plot).

```
library(lubridate)

tempdf$day <- date(tempdf$time)
tempdf$forPlotTime <- tempdf$time

date(tempdf$forPlotTime) <-
  "2016-01-01"
```

Then, I can pass that modified data.frame to `ggplot`. You will likely want to modify colors/labels, but this should get you a pretty good start.

```
ggplot(tempdf
       , aes(x = forPlotTime
             , y = val
             , col = as.factor(day))) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~var) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "6 hours"
                   , date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

Generates:

[image]